# WSO2 MB start-up Error

Tags: wso2, messagebroker

I have download WSO2 MB 2.1.0 and run it with the built-in Cassandra server in Windows 7 64bit.
But the start-up procedure  failed with the following error message.

> 

```
[2013-12-14 11:27:03,371] ERROR {org.apache.cassandra.service.AbstractCassandraD
aemon} -
Exception in thread Thread[Thread-21,5,main]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:713)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:949)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1371)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CustomTThreadPoolServer.serve(CustomTThre
   adPoolServer.java:103)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraDaemon$ThriftServer.run(Cassandr
   aDaemon.java:213)
[2013-12-14 11:27:03,396]  INFO {me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.JmxMonitor} -
Registering JMX me.prettyprint.cassandra.service_ClusterOne:ServiceType=hector,
MonitorType=hector
```

> 

I found a related bug issue: https://wso2.org/jira/browse/MB-210
Does anyone know if the next release will really fix this bug?
Or I have to use standalone deployment with external Cassandra server as this suggestion?
http://udarakr.blogspot.tw/2013/09/how-to-overcome-wso2-message-broker.html

Comment: I got the same issue when I deploy a standalone MB in linux environment. I fixed that issue increasing maximum number of processes/threads per user using "ulimit" in linux. You environment is Windows and you use cassandra server. So increasing that processes per user may solve your problem. but not sure exactly.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is something to do with Cassandra,In Linux i faced the same issue and once i increased the max user processes Everything went fine, Please refer  the article written on this topic [Unable to create new native thread and max user processes](http://vanjikumaran.blogspot.com/2014/01/unable-to-create-new-native-thread-and.html). Since this issue is occurring in Windows, [Better to Run Cassandra externally](http://docs.wso2.org/display/MB210/Standalone+Deployment+on++External+Cassandra+Server) and fine tune the Cassandra on it!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I run it on Linux and everything good.