# WSO2 Message broker not starting

Tags: wso2, wso2-message-broker

I have downloaded WSO2 MB recently and trying to start it but it is failing with below error.

```
[2015-09-14 15:30:48,594]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent} -  Mgt Console URL  : https://127.0.0.1:9443/carbon/
[2015-09-14 15:30:48,601]  WARN {me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.CassandraHostRetryService} -  Downed localhost(127.0.0.1):9160 host sti
ll appears to be down: Unable to open transport to localhost(127.0.0.1):9160 , java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
[2015-09-14 15:30:48,676] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.servlet.internal.RegistryAtomServiceComponent} -  ******* Failed to activate Regis
try APP bundle *******
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: (class: org/apache/abdera/i18n/text/data/UnicodeCharacterDatabase, method: getDecompIdx signature: ()[I)
        at org.apache.abdera.i18n.iri.IRI.preinit(IRI.java:659)
        at org.apache.abdera.Abdera.<init>(Abdera.java:90)
        at org.apache.abdera.Abdera.<init>(Abdera.java:81)
        at org.apache.abdera.protocol.server.ServiceManager.getAbdera(ServiceManager.java:57)
        at org.apache.abdera.protocol.server.ServiceManager.newProvider(ServiceManager.java:64)
        at org.apache.abdera.protocol.server.servlet.AbderaServlet.createProvider(AbderaServlet.java:78)
        at org.apache.abdera.protocol.server.servlet.AbderaServlet.init(AbderaServlet.java:61)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.init(ServletRegistration.java:49)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.registerServlet(ProxyServlet.java:179)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.HttpServiceImpl.registerServlet(HttpServiceImpl.java:66)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.servlet.internal.RegistryAtomServiceComponent.registerServlet(RegistryAtomServiceComponent.java:86)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.servlet.internal.RegistryAtomServiceComponent.activate(RegistryAtomServiceComponent.java:56)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:347)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.registerHttpService(Activator.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.addProxyServlet(Activator.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.init(ProxyServlet.java:40)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.init(DelegationServlet.java:38)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1267)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1186)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1081)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
[2015-09-14 15:30:48,686]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.server.registry.ApplicationRegistry} -  Shutting down ApplicationRegistry(org.wso2.andes.ser
ver.registry.ConfigurationFileApplicationRegistry@78606d)
[2015-09-14 15:30:48,689]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.server.registry.ApplicationRegistry} -  Shutting down ApplicationRegistry:org.wso2.andes.ser
ver.registry.ConfigurationFileApplicationRegistry@78606d

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-9"
[2015-09-14 15:30:48,705]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.server.security.auth.manager.PrincipalDatabaseAuthenticationManager} -  Unregistering UserMa
nagementMBean
[2015-09-14 15:30:56,287]  INFO {me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.CassandraHostRetryService} -  Not checking that localhost(127.0.0.1):91
60 is a member of the ring since there are no live hosts

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "CacheExpirySchedulerThread-97"
```

I have modified memory arguments to 512MB(actually I tried with different memory configuration also) but no luck. I am able to start other wso2 products on my machine without any problem. Please suggest.

More logs which are keep on coming are as below.

```
[2015-09-14 15:45:21,668]  WARN {me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.CassandraHostRetryService} -  Downed localhost(127.0.0.1):9160 host sti
ll appears to be down: Unable to open transport to localhost(127.0.0.1):9160 , java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
[2015-09-14 15:45:21,669]  INFO {me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.CassandraHostRetryService} -  Downed Host retry status false with host:
 localhost(127.0.0.1):9160
```

Comment: I am using Windows7 OS with 8gb RAM and I can see that only ~4gb is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found one solution is to run cassandra externally and fine tune it.

Reference: [WSO2 MB start-up Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20624546/wso2-mb-start-up-error)

Answer (score 0):

When you run the WSO2 Message Broker in Stand-Alone Mode (with internal Cassandra), you need more than 512 MB Memory. In my case only the startup took up to 700 MB.

Change the Memory in the bin/wso2server.bat File:
[image]

Please change this value as you have enough memory available on your system.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried between 512 MB -2048 MB range but problem remains same. Apart from it, I tried to start same WSO2 Message Broker on different machines and started without any problem (copied same software on 3 machines with same configuration). I can see that it is showing 'Unable to obtain native thread' so suspecting if any mismatch/configuration problem at OS level.